# Does using Projection Expressinos in querying DynamoDB reduce the read capacity unit comsumption?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, database, nosql

Have been going through the DynamoDB documentation, but couldn't verify the following.

1. What is the main purpose of ProjectionExpression in DynamoDB?
2. Does it reduce the read capacity unit consumption?
3. If not - Dynamodb charges the same amount irrespective of if you read the entire item  or just a few attributes?

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

1. By using a `ProjectionExpression`, you decrease the amount of data transferred between DynamoDB and your application, thereby limiting network bandwidth.
2. It doesn't. I tried, but couldn't find official documentation on this. But if you look at [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryingJavaDocumentAPI.html) on `Query`, it says that a filter, from a `FilterExpression`, "is applied after the query is processed, but before the results are returned to the user". I would assume the same behavior for `ProjectionExpression`s.
3. Similar to #2 above, you'd be charged for reading the entire item, not just the attributes you requested. Another proof of this is [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ProvisionedThroughput.html#HowItWorks.ProvisionedThroughput.Reads) documentation on how they calculate read/write units. They never mention attributes separately.

Answer (score 11):

According to AWS CLI Command Reference: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/dynamodb/query.html
"DynamoDB calculates the number of read capacity units consumed based on item size, not on the amount of data that is returned to an application. The number of capacity units consumed will be the same whether you request all of the attributes (the default behavior) or just some of them (using a projection expression). The number will also be the same whether or not you use a FilterExpression"